# bash: get error trying to continue to run commands in oneliner after running app

Tags: bash

I whipped up the following oneliner to create a quick `audacious` playlist from command line using `find` search results:

```
mp3s=() ; while read -r -d $'\0'; do mp3s+=("$REPLY") ; done < <(find . -type f -iname "*every*.mp3" -print0) ; audacious "${mp3s[0]}" & ; for f in "${mp3s[@]:1}" ; do audtool --playlist-addurl "$f" ; done
```

but I think because I want to run audacious and free up the command line afterwards to continue running commands, I get the following error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

which is fixed if I first run:

```
mp3s=() ; while read -r -d $'\0'; do mp3s+=("$REPLY") ; done < <(find . -type f -iname "*every*.mp3" -print0) ; audacious "${mp3s[0]}"
```

and then:

```
for f in "${mp3s[@]:1}" ; do audtool --playlist-addurl "$f" ; done
```

Is there a way around having to split this oneliner into 2 separate commands so they can be run as a single command?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and replace `& ;` by `&`.

Comment: @Cyrus omitting `;` after `&` creates the playlist with only the first element of array, spitting bac following error: ` so still nothing after the `&` is being run

Comment: @scriptz: Spitting back what error? (watch out for angle brackets). Anyway, you have a race condition since it is not guaranteed that `audacious` will actually have started before `audtool` is run. BTW, bash commands are terminated with *either* `&` or `;`, but empty commands are not allowed, so `;;` is not valid, and neither is `& &` or `&;` (or, for that matter, `;&`).

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing why you want to run a separate instance of audtool on every file (it seems rather inefficient), I'd suggest something simpler like this:

```
find . -type f -iname "*every*.mp3" -print0 | xargs -0 audacious
```

Or if you have too many files to fit on one command line:

```
find $PWD -type f -iname "*every*.mp3" -fprint temp.m3u ; audacious temp.m3u
```